# Azure Data Factory is Git enabled, but I don't have option to use Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am trying work on our ADF, but getting the message that I need to gain access to the repository before I can publish any changes. However, when I try access the repository it's greyed out

[image]

Can you let me know what is needed to be able to access the repository?

I guess I will need to gain the relevant permission to access the Azure DevOps repo, but what do I need to request in order to be able to actually select Azure DevOps Git from within ADF?

Comment: You'll need to be added to the Project's team in the Azure DevOps portal, that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This access is inherited based on the user's logged in credentials. You will need to have contributor access to the ADO project and a valid ADO license when attempting to configure ADF to integrate with ADO.